# same printf gives different results

Tags: c++, printf

This is my first post and hope this is not a repost.
I wrote the following c++ program on mac using g++ to compile.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
int main ()
{

    double b = 1;
    printf("%x\n", b);
    printf("%x\n", b);
    printf("%x\n", b);
    printf("%x\n", b);
    return 0;

}
```

why the program gives me different results of the same code? Here is the output.

```
5ca5ebf8
100
200
300
```

This behavior is not shown in VS on Windows though.
thanks.

Comment: Might be undefined behavior? http://codepad.org/lICuNfdM

Comment: Well, I wouldn't expect that, even though using `"%x"` for `double` is generally *Undefined Behavior*.

Comment: It's undefined behavior, anything can happen.

Comment: There is indeed a trend here,suggesting this is not completely "undefined". The output will continue to be 400, 500, 600, .... Thanks anyway.

Comment: THere's something more: You are missing the header for `printf`. That might contribute an additional UB.

Comment: Undefined doesn't mean it doesn't do the same thing every time on the same platform, it just means it can do anything.

Comment: Try adding `#include <stdio.h>`. Also, ask for all warnings and handle them.

Comment: Perhaps the compiler optimized it to a loop

Comment: Just tried adding the header, no change.

Comment: I am studying how float numbers are stored in memory, I know change %x to %f will work, this is just for fun. thanks again, I did not expect I could get response this quick

Answer (score 0):

This is the warning you should get with any decent compiler: `warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'double'`

So you get undefined behaviour, anything can happen :)